# Good Open source avenues to work on OS / low level distributed system stuff

Tags: kernel, distributed-computing

Or rather, if I'm reading  "Understanding the Linux Kernel" and more of Linux/OS level or more low level dist. computing stuff, what kind of open source projects are worthing taking a look at - except of course the Linux distros.

Thanks

Ajay

Comment: Educational oses like Pintos or Minix may be a good idea